# Play framework Reverse Routing

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

What exactly is reverse routing in play framework? I am new to Java and currently working on java play framework. I've read the play framework documentation but don't get any idea of reverse routing. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Routing is the process that will transform an http request's method and path into a controller call.

Reverse-routing is the opposite, it allows you to get a method and path from a controller call.

For example, when the browser sends `GET /api/user/login`, the router triggers a call to `controllers.user.login()`. Now the reverse router helps you when you wonder: *how to have the browser make a call to `controllers.user.login()`*, the reverse router will basically answer you: `GET /api/user/login`.